# Find huge blocks of allocated memory

Tags: c++, c, memory, valgrind

I have a program (daemon) that is written in c/c++. It runs flawlessly, but after some period of time( it can be 5 days, week, 2 weeks ) it becomes to allocate a lot of megabytes of memory. I can't understand what parts of code do not free allocated memory. At startup memory usage is about 20-30 megabytes. Then after some period, or maybe event, it grows slowly about 1Mb per hour, and if not terminated can crash because no memory is available.

I've tried to use Valgrind and did shutdown the daemon in usual way when it has already allocated about 500Mb of memory. Shutdown process was really long, but when it finished Valgrind said no memory leaks were found, except for mysql_init/mysql_close procedures(about 504bytes are definetly lost). Google says not to worry about this Mysql leak, and gives some reasons why memory diagnostic tools like Valgrind think that it is a leak.

I don't really know what parts of code allocate memory but free it only on program shutdown. Help me to find out this

Comment: Your code may not be leaking memory in the traditional sense, but these types of resource issues crop up from time to time and are usually difficult to find even if you know the code in and out.  Without seeing your code it is impossible to tell what is happening.

Comment: Valgrind's tool Massif will probably be more useful in this case than the default tool Memcheck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valgrind only detects pointers that aren't deleted, more or less. Keeping them around when you don't need them is a different problem.

Firstly, all objects and memory are freed at shutdown. If there's a leak, valgrind will detect it as memory not referenced by an object, etc. Any leaks however are freed by the operating system in the end.

If you're catching all exceptions (...) and not doing anything with them, well, don't do that. It's a common cause.

Secondly, a logfile of destructors that are called during shutdown might be helpful. Perhaps at the end of main(), set a global flag; any destructors called while that flag is set can output that they exist. See if there are lots of objects that shouldn't be there.

A bit easier, you can use a global variable, each ctor can increment it by 1, and dtor decrement by 1. If you find that the number of objects isn't staying relatively the same, you can investigate which ones are making the problem using similar techniques.

Thirdly, use Boost and its scoped smart pointers to help, but do not rely on smart pointers as the holy grail.

There is a possible underlying issue that I have come across. For long-running programs, memory fragmentation can lead to large memory usage. You may delete a 1mb object, then try to create a 2mb object; the creation will be in new space because that 1mb 'free chunk' is not big enough. Then when you make a 512kb object it may go into that 1mb object's space, only using 1/2 of available space, but making it so that your next 1mb object needs to be allocated in big space.

Unfortunately this problem can become bad, due to small objects being allocated in persistent places. There may be, say, 50-byte classes 300kb apart in memory, and like 100 of them, but no 512kb objects can be allocated in that space, so it allocates an additional 512kb for each new object, effectively wasting 90% of actual 'free' space even though your program owns more than enough already.

This problem is hard to track down as the definite cause, but if you examine your program's flow, look for small allocations. Remember std::list/vector/etc. can all cause this; if you're looking to make a daemon that does lots of memory ops run for weeks, it's a good idea to pre-allocate memory using reserve(). Memory pools are even better.

Depending on the time you want to put in, you can also either make (or find) a custom memory allocator that will report on objects when it shuts down, too.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use Valgrind Massif tool. From [Massif manual](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html#ms-manual.overview):

> Also, there are certain space leaks that aren't detected by
> traditional leak-checkers, such as Memcheck's. That's because the
> memory isn't ever actually lost -- a pointer remains to it -- but it's
> not in use. Programs that have leaks like this can unnecessarily
> increase the amount of memory they are using over time. Massif can
> help identify these leaks.

Massif should show you what's happening with memory and where it is allocated and not freeing until shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sure, there's no memory leak, your program might be allocating memory and storing data without leaking.

For example, let's say your program uses a linked list...

```
struct list{
DATA_ARRAY arr; //Some data 
struct *list next;
};

While(true) //infinite loop
{
// Add new nodes to list 
// Store some data in the node
}
```

There's no leak here. But the loop adds new nodes forever and stores data and everything is perfectly valid. But memory usage increases all the time. Since you are running for 2-5 days, something like this is certainly possible.

You may have to inspect the code and free memory if no longer needed.